# (udisks-error-quark, 0) error while trying to open my USB flash memory

Tags: mount, usb-flash-drive, quark

I had an Ubuntu 22.04 running wth no problems but decided to change my SSD card and install the exact same Ubuntu on a new SSD. So I copied some important files into a USB flash memory and after it finished I checked to see if all files have been copied, so that was.

Then I changed the SSD and installed the same Ubuntu on the new SSD and tried the flash memory to reach my files but I get `unknown  (udisks-error-quark, 0)` error when I try to open the flash memory.

[image]

When I use `disks` to mount it:

[image]

Comment: Missing filesystem? find and install that! e.g. exfat, ntfs, ...

Comment: "So I copied **some** important files." Obviously, not all files, nor have you duplicated the full disk. Why not use dd to image one SSD to another?? Just run dd from a live USB, so you have full access to original. It's *fast* to make a disk image -- just delete any unwanted stuff later.

Comment: @Hannu: May you explain more? I am not a Linux expert.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik: Unfortunately as my laptop only supports one SSD at a time, I rewrote the previous one with 0s because I thought I would never use that 128G SSD card again!

Comment: Then the best alternative might be 1. Save files to other media (e.g., USB drive) 2. Format SSD. 3. Install Ubuntu (it only takes a few minutes) 4. Copy saved files to SSD.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik: I think we are not in a same page. I had Ubuntu installed on my previous SSD. I decided to improve my laptop with a new SSD I'd bought. I copied my files from previous Ubuntu(SSD) to a USB flash memory. Then Formated the previous SSD and installed Ubuntu on the new SSD(using second flash memory).

Comment: Then after I tried to open the( first) flash memory contains my important files within the new Ubuntu installed on new SSD, but I got the above errors! What I am trying to do is fixing and openning the USB memory that contains my files that I had copied from previous Ubuntu on previous SSD.

Answer (score 3):

Consider doing this

Open the "Disks" on ubuntu.
select the faulty disk
setting --> repair filesystem

solved the problem and let you mount the drive

Answer (score 1):

Start a Terminal / Bash / Shell

*(HOW: Hold* <kbd>CTRL</kbd> *and* <kbd>ALT</kbd>, *hit* <kbd>T</kbd>).

... when the `$` (the prompt) appears, type

```
$ sudo apt install exfat-fuse exfat-utils ntfs-3g
```

... then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

This will first request your password, then install the driver and utils / tools for `exfat` a filesystem similar to "FAT" or "VFAT" and also the Linux `NTFS`, either of which you **might** need;

**but: I'm only guessing** - as  you have not provided details about your USB-stick/flash-mem.

*NOTE: You MIGHT already **have** these installed, as per default, or even NOT NEED them - I'm not sure about though. The above is a way to ensure it.*

---

You may also try:

```
$ lsblk -fape7
```

... and copy the output into your question, then select the text and hold+hit `CTRL+K` (and save)

This will tell if `lsblk` recognizes how your flash-drive is formatted.

Comment: Recent kernel has driver for exfat though, although I have no idea how recent is needed exactly. There has also been a new ntfs kernel driver (although ntfs-3g might still be more preferred).